# fs is not defined in bundle.js despite being in package.json and in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

> fs is not defined in bundle.js

this appears to be a generated file, because when I go to add the import 'fs', it changes the file back as soon as i restart the server.

the code in question is at the very end of the bundle.js file:

```
(fs, path, url, require$$0$1, buffer, assert, util);
```

Comment: `fs` is a nodejs API. Are you trying to use it in a clientside bundle? What do you mean by "*being in package.json and in node_modules*"?

Comment: im using a separate node module that pulls in api data that the svelte component reads and should display. the build.js file has the fs module that is coming from the alpaca module

Comment: Are you using svelte for server-side rendering or for client-side display in the browser? Please post your code that attempts to use the filesystem (or use the alpaca module)